# Unable to store log data in JSON format using Log4Net appender in c# .NET, what am I missing?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

I am new in c# .NET and trying to create an application with Log4Net logger, but unable to store log data in JSON format. however, I am able to store logs in the text file.

I have created log4net.config file and below is the configuration I am using. but the logger.log file (which I am expecting to be JSON file) is not creating.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<log4net>

    <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="C:\Users\user1\source\repos\Log4netExample\Log4netExample\Logs\log.txt" />
        <staticLogFileName value="false" />
        <rollingStyle value="Date" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    
        <appender name="JsonLogging" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
       <file value="C:\Users\user1\source\repos\Log4netExample\Log4netExample\Logs\logger.log" />
      <staticLogFileName value="false" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.SerializedLayout, log4net.Ext.Json">
                    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
        <decorator type="log4net.Layout.Decorators.StandardTypesDecorator, log4net.Ext.Json" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="ALL"/>
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
        <appender-ref ref="JsonLogging" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

Comment: Is that config valid? A conversion pattern tag in a json appender seems odd. Maybe activate self logging to see if there is something.

Comment: Yes, it is valid JSON. after installing 'log4net.Ext.Json' nuget package I am able to generate logs in JSON file but they are not in valid JSON format.